# how to create custom theme in magento 1.7.2?

Tags: magento, themes

I am new to magento. I want to create a magento custom theme.I follow this [tutorial](http://zaclee.net/magento/make-magento-1-6-theme-from-scratch) but its mentioned as 1.6 version.Some directory structure are not available in 1.7.how to creating custom theme in Magento 1.7